# Where can i store my rocksDB state on AWS Managed Apache Flink?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink

I'm writing a Flink job to store state and perform aggregations using RocksDB, but I am unsure where I can let RocksDB store state. On my local machine, I was storing it at ~/Downloads/flink-1.15.4/rocksdb/. But in AWS, I am unable to use a store like file:///rocksdb/. I have also tried storing on S3.

Both of these methods have not worked, I am trying to avoid having to use EFS because of high costs. What's the best way to do this?

For my checkpointing itself, I am able to use S3 (while setting checkpoint storage of my env). This seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, `rocksdb.localdir` should always point to a local disk. This is where RocksDB will keep the working state, and having to read and write from S3 (for example) on every state access would be very painful.

I can't see any reason to use EFS; EBS is fine. Choose SSDs if you care about performance.

It's fine if `rocksdb.localdir` uses ephemeral storage. Since Flink relies on the checkpoints for recovery, it doesn't matter if the local disk survives. Some folks even use a RAM disk for the RocksDB local storage.

Comment: Do you know any resource I can look at to configure EBS access for my Flink application running on Managed Apache Flink?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Managed Apache Flink.